# how to make html5 working with android

Tags: android, html

is the html5 working on android 2.2 and above?
i was tried a [youtube link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVqp1zcMfbE), but it is working with js.
they just adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` that all then say is support html5?
and i tried to put other html5 coding as below

```
<form action="/newaccount" method=post
  oninput="up2.setCustomValidity(up2.value != up.value ? 'Passwords do not match.' : '')">
<p>
<label for="username">E-mail address:</label>
<input id="username" type=email required name=un>
</p>
<label for="password1">Password:</label>
<input id="password1" type=password required name=up>
<p>
<label for="password2">Confirm password:</label>
<input id="password2" type=password name=up2>
</p>
<input type=submit value="Create account" />
</form>
```

is it html5 must with jquery or javascript then will working at my android device 2.3.6?
is it now html5 full support with android 4.0 only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to explore Phone Gap. Its a platform-independent development environment which converts apps written with HTML5, CSS and JS into publish-ready Android, IPhone, Windows etc apps.

http://phonegap.com/

Comment: this one i knew it..is it now only this software can do html5 and compatible with Android, IPhone, Windows etc?

Answer (score 3):

yes html5 is working on android 2.2 and above.
 
[html5 support with android browser](http://mobilehtml5.org/)

its possible that your emulator does not support some feature.
try to run your app in device.

Comment: already tried...not work..should i post the full script?
i do `type=email` using the youtube method i posted above, however it doesn't working..

Answer (score 1):

No browser currently fully support HTML5, but some support most of the specifications.
The built-in browser of Android 2.2 does support the type=email specification.

Answer (score 1):

`<!DOCTYPE html>` only applies when making a webpage.
It converts basic html to html5.

Html5 on Android 2.2 only supports:

1. <!DOCTYPE html>
2. 2D Context
3. Text
4. Selection of elements - embedding custom non visible data
5. Dynamic mark up insertion
6. Base64 encoding and decoding
7. Cross document messaging
8. One field type- input type=text

HOWEVER, it doesnt support:

`html5 tokenizer, html tree building, svg in text/html, mathML in text/html,video element, subtitle support, poster image support, MPEG-4, Audio, MP3`

Nearly all field types:

```
input type=search
input type=tel
input type=url
input type=email
input type=datetime
input type=date
input type=month
input type=week
input type=time
input type=datetime-local
input type=range
input type=color
input type=checkbox
input type=image
textarea
select
datalist
keygen
output
progress
field validation
form validation
APIs
Spellcheck attribute
Session history
Geolocation
Device Orientation
FileReader API
Local Storage
Access the camera
Full Screen
```

But Google say it does well in SandWich Ice Cream